# Servlet + Tomcat 6: referencing javaScript library

Tags: tomcat, javascript

I'm writting a small JSP page, which should use a JavaScript library, but I have problem with resolving this library. To test the issue I created a simple web app and added the following HTML-file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc2/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo1" class="demo">
        <ul>
            <li id="phtml_1">
                <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="phtml_2" class="jstree-checked">
                        <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="phtml_3">
                        <a href="#">Child node 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="phtml_4">
                <a href="#">Root node 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" class="source">
        $(function () {
            $("#demo1").jstree({
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox" ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This works fine, but it doesn't work if I replace "http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc2/jquery.jstree.js" with "scripts/jquery.jstree.js", though all libraries are in the same scripts folder (src/main/webapp/scripts).

Any idea what is going wrong?

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I didn't copy the themes to my project :-/

Thanks anyway.